# How can i show/hide the label on dropdown selection change using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to show and hide the label name based on the dropdown selection using jquery i am using the below jquery code but it is not working

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlselect').on('change', function () {
                if (this.value == '1')
                {
                    $("#dvtype").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#dvtype").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
    <label for="dvtype">Type</label>
    <select id="ddlselect" style="width: 55px;"></select>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us which error comes ?

Comment: That code works perfectly fine: what do you mean by "not working"? Have you checked that jquery is loaded on your page? Have you checked that the element `#ddlselect` is already in the DOM at runtime? What does the console say?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set `ID`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlselect').on('change', function () {
            if (this.value == '1')
            {
                $("#dvtype").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#dvtype").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="dvtype" for="dvtype">Type</label>
<select id="ddlselect" style="width: 55px;">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">1</option>
<option value="3">1</option>
<option value="4">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but there is an issue after hiding i have four elements in td when the second element is hided the third and fourth elements should occupy the second once place and when second element is shown third and fourth element should come to its original place which is not happening <tr><td style="width:70px; cursor: pointer; padding-left: 25px" align="left">Maths</td><td style="width:180px"><label id="dvtype" for="dvtype">Type</label></td><td style="width:160px">From Date</td><td style="width:180px">To Date</td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlselect').on('change', function () {
            if (this.value == '1')
            {
                $("#dvtype").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#dvtype").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="dvtype">Type</label>
<select id="ddlselect" style="width: 55px;">
   <option label="Show" value="1">Show</option>
  <option label="Hide"  value="0">Hide</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but there is an issue after hiding i have four elements in td when the second element is hided the third and fourth elements should occupy the second once place and when second element is shown third and fourth element should come to its original place which is not happening <tr><td style="width:70px; cursor: pointer; padding-left: 25px" align="left">Maths</td><td style="width:180px"><label id="dvtype" for="dvtype">Type</label></td><td style="width:160px">From Date</td><td style="width:180px">To Date</td></tr>

Comment: could you please paste the code you have and expected output

Answer (score 0):

add id in the label tag like;

```
<label for="dvtype" id="dvtype">Type</label>
```

Your code didnt work because the jquery selector, i.e. $('#dvtype'), doesnot know what it is pointing to hence the ID.

Comment: but there is an issue after hiding i have four elements in td when the second element is hided the third and fourth elements should occupy the second once place and when second element is shown third and fourth element should come to its original place which is not happening <tr><td style="width:70px; cursor: pointer; padding-left: 25px" align="left">Maths</td><td style="width:180px"><label id="dvtype" for="dvtype">Type</label></td><td style="width:160px">From Date</td><td style="width:180px">To Date</td></tr>

Comment: if u want to hide the <td> itself based on the selected option, then do the following; if (this.value == '1') { $("#dvtype").closest('td').show(); } else { $("#dvtype").closest('td').hide(); }